# Is there any way to know when Shift+Enter was pressed in iPad keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard

I would like to customize my input a little and I wonder if that is possible?

For example I would like to add a Bullet to my textView when Enter is pressed and do the usual thing when Shift+Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself: Forget about this, I believe is not possible. (I blame Apple!) I just implemented the bullet when Enter is input twice.